# using "for" loop read a file line by line continuously by considering each line as a input

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, variable, for

Consider a file.txt file with below values

```
one,two
three,four
five,six
six,seven
red,tree
```

Need a shell script command to perform below activity

1. For loop in which the loop should be continuously executed with as many number of lines the file.txt has
2. In each loop execution, the respective line should be considered a input for the execution.

For example, in first loop execution, "one" should be stored in a variable and "two" should be stored in another variable so that it will use the variable values in execution

```
Input1="one"
Input2="two"
```

Similary for second line execution, "three" should be stored in a variable and "four" should be stored in another variable like below

```
Input1="three"
Input2="four"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while IFS=, read -r input1 input2; do
    # do stuff with "$input1" and "$input2"
done <file.txt
```

Setting `IFS` to a comma for the `read` command will make it split each input line on commas.  The two fields of the line will be read into `input1` and `input2`.

If there are more fields than two on any line, the "left over" data will be put into `input2`.

Depending on what you want to do with the data, this may or may not be a good idea at all.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

You will notice that `awk` is particularly useful for parsing data like this, without the need for a loop:

```
$ awk -F, '{ printf("Line %d:\n\tField 1 = %s\n\tField 2 = %s\n", NR, $1, $2) }' file.txt
Line 1:
        Field 1 = one
        Field 2 = two
Line 2:
        Field 1 = three
        Field 2 = four
Line 3:
        Field 1 = five
        Field 2 = six
Line 4:
        Field 1 = six
        Field 2 = seven
Line 5:
        Field 1 = red
        Field 2 = tree
```

Comment: In order to avoid all additional input being lumped into `input2` you can create a third var to collect it all:  `while IFS=, read -r input1 input2 garbage; do`

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what you're asking. Why do you need the whole file in each iteration.

Do you need this?

```
while IFS=, read -r Input1 Input2; do
    # do something with the variables
    echo "1=$Input1  2=$Input2"
done < file.txt
```